# How to add to an observable array using knockout mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to add a json item to an observable array, and in a `foreach` rendering, it shows up. But when I try to access the item using `item.property()` syntax, it fails but only for the post-initial-binding item. Better explained with code...

Js:

```
var data = { colors: []};
data.colors.push({title: 'blue' });
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.colors.push({ title: 'red' });

$("#out").html("<br/>colors are ...<br/>");
$.each(vm.colors(), function(i, clr) {
 $("#out").append(clr.title() + "<br/>");
});
```

Output: (note, "red" isn't spit out :/)

```
blue
red

colors are ...
blue
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ivacuw/7/edit

I've also tried doing `vm.colors( [ { title: 'red' }] )` instead of the `vm.colors.push(...)`, but same issue. Error of `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'title' of object #<Object> is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the red color. The title is a string, so not a ko.observable.
That's why you can't call it.

The problem doesn't occur on the blue title because you call the fromJS function that converts the blue string into ko.observable(string).

```
var data = { colors: []};
data.colors.push({title: 'blue'});
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

//fix 
vm.colors.push({ title: ko.observable('red') });
$("#out").html("<br/>colors are ...<br/>");
$.each(vm.colors(), function(i, clr) {
    $("#out").append(clr.title() + "<br/>");
});
```

@Ian Davis

If I understood you right. You can do that :

```
[...]
//vm.colors.push({ title: 'red' });
var arr = [{title:'green'},{title:'yellow'}];
ko.utils.arrayForEach(arr, function(item) {vm.colors.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item)); });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway to add the array in one line? Example, `var arr = [{title:'green'},{title:'yellow'}]` then later, `vm.colors = ko.observableArray(arr)` perhaps?

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to work. http://jsbin.com/ivacuw/16/edit maybe this isn't possible and I just have to add them one by one..?

Comment: Why do you add one item (blue) and then the others ? Why don't you add all items at the same time ?

Comment: because in my actual project, I have a set of just blue, then later on, via ajax, i'm adding more colors. or, via ajax I'm replacing the entire set of colors.